# How to run XDebug with PHPUnit from the command line?

Tags: windows, netbeans, phpunit

I have netbeans running in debug mode. Now I want to run a unit tests with ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug with the goal of having breakpoints as I go. Is it possible?

I tried something like this:

```
phpunit myTest.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

Doesn't work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

According to this: http://blog.doh.ms/2011/05/13/debugging-phpunit-tests-in-netbeans-with-xdebug/

> Go to command line and run phpunit-debug. Now debugging starts, if you selected “Stop on first line” phpunit file will be opened on your IDE, click play and you are off.

If I run phpunit --debug

```
Starting test 'xxxx'
OK (1 test, 4 assertions)
```

Problem is, it never caught the breakpoint that I had in a controller. Why won't it catch it? Is it possible due to the fact that it is executed using:

```
$this->dispatch('/ajax/update-bla');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this
$ XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug" phpunit -c %yourconfing%.xml

or you can export shell var
$ export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug"
and then just run phpunit as usual
$ phpunit -c %yourconfing%.xml

Comment: Also you can also create a `phpunit-debug` bash loader, very useful: http://www.stephenrhoades.com/?p=600

Comment: I didn't understood. This must be run on the terminal? The configuration file has something important for the debug work?